# Tamper Monkey code : Copy Text from a certain part of the Webpage

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

Hi I am trying to find a tamper monkey code where I can copy the text of a webpage. Its at the same place every time. Its an Open Street Map Edit Mode. I have the code to copy Latlongs from a normal OSM(URL) But edit mode URL isn't the same. Need Help.[Here is Picture of what I am trying to copy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjYnT.png)

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var radButton = document.createElement('input');
radButton.id = 'rad-button';
radButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
radButton.value = 'Copy Geocodes';
radButton.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; z-index: 2500; padding: 5px; left: 40px; top:650px; background-color: #282828; color: #FFFFFF; border: 4px solid #282828; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 40px; font-family: Sans serif; font-weight: bold;');
radButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const latlongURL = "Need to copy the latlongs in the Image here everytime a button is clicked";
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var radButton = document.createElement('input');
    radButton.id = 'rad-button';
    radButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    radButton.value = 'Copy Geocodes';
    radButton.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; z-index: 2500; padding: 5px; left: 40px; top:770px; background-color: #282828; color: #FFFFFF; border: 4px solid #282828; border-radius: 8px; font-size: 40px; font-family: Sans serif; font-weight: bold;');
    radButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
       ** var final = document.querySelector("#id-container > div.main-content.active > div.over-map > div.info-panels > div > div.panel-content.panel-content-measurement > ul > li:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3)").innerHTML; **
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).